# what is the meaning of setStartPoint in jgit when you move branch?

Tags: git, jgit

I created two branches with start point to origin/master
does it have any meaning when i checkout the branches ( move between the branches ) with parameter of start Point ? 
What happened if I move or not moved the parameter startPoint when I checkout branches?

Comment: `startPoint` is basically the commit the branch is based on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see setStartPoint used for [`createBranch`](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/a9b1b62e9e521da57d54f755568d16874e86cb40/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowBranchDiff.java#L51) (also [in this example](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/a9b1b62e9e521da57d54f755568d16874e86cb40/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/unfinished/TrackMaster.java#L57-L63))

```
    Ref ref = git.branchCreate().setName("testbranch").setStartPoint("origin/testbranch").call();
```

You can also set a startpoint on a checkout command, when you want to checkout not the HEAD of a branch, but a previous commit.
[Example](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/b601e88738945b3861b99283173e31daf924227d/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PathCheckoutCommandTest.java#L194-L202):

```
    CheckoutCommand co = git.checkout();
    File test = writeTrashFile(FILE1, "");
    File test2 = writeTrashFile(FILE2, "");
    co.setStartPoint("HEAD~2").addPath(FILE1).addPath(FILE2).call();
```

> What happened if I move or not moved the parameter startPoint when I checkout branches

You would checkout HEAD (no startPoint specified) or you would checkout another commit from the branch checked out.