# RefNotFoundException when creating a branch in JGIT

Tags: java, branch, jgit

I have a problem where i cannot create local branch.

```
Error: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref origin/sideMerge cannot be resolved
```

I have checked the following [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130665/what-is-the-meaning-of-setstartpoint-in-jgit-when-you-move-branch) and some others in Stackoverflow but it seems something fishy going on or something i don't understand yet.

Can someone point me to a direction what i don't understand regarding the Ref ? 
As far as i know the local refs starts from origin/"other_branch"

Code snippet:

```
Git git;
    CreateBranchCommand tmpCreateBranch;
    git = new Git(existingRepo);
    tmpCreateBranch = git.branchCreate();

    try {
        tmpCreateBranch.setName(tmpBranchName).setStartPoint("origin/" + tmpBranchName).setForce(true).call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in Branch creation");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: The error message says that there is no branch named `origin/sideMerge`. Did you check a remote tracking branch actually exists? Also, try to use the full ref name: `refs/remotes/origin/sideMerge`.

Comment: I don't want to make it to remote. i just create it locally for merging purposes. Once im done with merging im deleting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Git manual, you can create a branch using the following syntax. It creates a new branch head named `<branchname>` which points to the current HEAD, or `<start-point>` if given:

```
git branch [--track | --no-track] [-l] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]
```

Therefore, you can create a local branch *"topic"* by following the similar syntax in JGit (see next code-block). In this case, you didn't configure the start-point explicitly. JGit will use HEAD as start-point. So everything works fine:

```
git.branchCreate().setName("topic").call();
```

However, if you create a local branch with start-point `origin/topic`, JGit will try to find this reference in [Git References](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References). In this context, `origin` is the name of the remote, and `topic` is the name of the branch. If not found, it raises an exception:

```
git.branchCreate().setName("topic").setStartPoint("origin/topic").call();
```

You also need to be aware that:

- `setForce(true)` will reset the target branch name to start-point if branch name exists already. Without `-f,--force` git branch refuses to change an existing branch.

Answer (score 0):

Szilágyi István, I create the branch as follows:

`try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
   Ref ref = git.branchCreate().setName("Name_Branch").setStartPoint("origin/develop").call();
   git.checkout().setName(branch).call();
   git.push().setCredentialsProvider(userService.getCredencialsProvider()).call();
   logger.info("Branch created: " + ref + " - " + ref.getName() + " - " + ref.getObjectId().getName());
}`

Comment: So basically you set "name_Branch" as a name for the branch and added a different reference? origin/develop? I think in my case that would cause a lot of confusion. But thank you for the answer.